# How to compute the image of the set $A$ under the complex logarithm function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, logarithms

I have given the function $\log:\Bbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ which denote the principal branch of complex logarithm.
I need to compute $log(A)$ where $A=\{z: Re(z)>0, |z|<1\}$.

My idea was the following. I take $z\in A$. Then $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $0<r<1$ and $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Then $\log(z)=\log(r)+\theta i$ where $\log(r)\in (-\infty, 0)$ and $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Hence I think that $\log(A)=\left\{z:Re(z)\in (-\infty, 0), Im(z)\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\}$

Is this correct so?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite right.

For $z\in \mathbb C\backslash(-\infty,0]$, we can write $z = re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$. Then $\log(z) = \log(r) + i\theta$.

Since $|z| = r$ and $\Re(z) = r\cos(\theta)$, we have :
$$z \in A\Longleftrightarrow r\in(0,1) \text{ and }\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$$
Therefore :
$$\log(A) = \{z\in \mathbb C | \Re(z) <0 \text{ and } -\pi/2 <\Im(z) <\pi/2\}$$

Comment: Ah oh sure, I made a mistake, I will correct it.